# How to run system() command in R script

Tags: r, system

I have a local server insalled on my system and have to start that from within my R function.

here is how I start it:

```
cmd<-"sh start-server.sh"  
system(cmd, wait=FALSE)
```

I have to perform computations after starting the server. Basically my function has to start the server and proceeds with further steps.
The server  starts but the further steps of the program are not executed.The cursor keeps waiting after the server is started.

Please suggest how to go about this.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5472562/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 2):

My problem is finally solved. I had to add Sys.sleep() and it runs after waiting for few seconds. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine whether or not the problem is with the server script or with R's execution of the script.  Try:

1. Running `sh start-server.sh` directly from a command prompt and seeing what happens.
2. Running something simple via R's `system` function, e.g., `system("ls", wait = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `system` waits for the executed command to terminate before returning. Add `wait=FALSE` if you want it to return immediately.